# Подсветить рамку картинки при наведении на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

При наведении на кнопку, необходимо подсветить рамку картинки, которая находится на одном уровне с кнопкой.
Сделал при помощи метода JQ hover, но почему то не работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let btn_buy = $('.item__buy');

  btn_buy.hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings('item__pic-wrapper').css('border-color', '#2ecc71');
  })

});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 225px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__pic-wrapper {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.item .item__pic-1 {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item .item__pic-1 {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150") no-repeat center;
}

.item .item__desc {
  margin: 18px auto 14px;
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__price {
  color: #2ecc71;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__price .-discount {
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.item .item__btn {
  margin: 16px auto 0;
  width: 171px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 200ms;
}

.item .item__btn .item__link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item .item__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.item .item__buy {
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: #95a5a6;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #95a5a6;
}

.item .item__buy:hover {
  color: #2ecc71;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__pic-wrapper">
    <div class="item__pic-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__desc">
    Описание
  </div>
  <div class="item__price">
    цена
  </div>
  <div class="item__btn">
    <a href="#" class="item__link">В корзину</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="item__buy">Купить в один клик</a>
</div>
```

Comment: вы точно уверены, что сделали с `hover()` ?

Comment: @teran да, просто проверял другие варианты и не заметил

Comment: во первых исправьте селектор (у вас там точка пропущена), а во вторых учтите, что hover выполняется сначала когда мышь наводится на элемент, а затем когда убирается. То есть вам надо не только менять границу на какой то цвет, но и возвращать его обратно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

точку пропустили

```js
const btn = $('.item__buy');

btn.hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.item__pic-wrapper').css('border-color', '#2ecc71');
});
```

```css
.item {
  width: 225px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__pic-wrapper {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.item .item__pic-1 {
  width: 225px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item .item__pic-1 {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/225/200/150") no-repeat center;
}

.item .item__desc {
  margin: 18px auto 14px;
  color: #34495e;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__price {
  color: #2ecc71;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item .item__price .-discount {
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.item .item__btn {
  margin: 16px auto 0;
  width: 171px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 200ms;
}

.item .item__btn .item__link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item .item__btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.item .item__buy {
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: #95a5a6;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #95a5a6;
}

.item .item__buy:hover {
  color: #2ecc71;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #2ecc71;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__pic-wrapper">
    <div class="item__pic-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__desc">
    Описание
  </div>
  <div class="item__price">
    цена
  </div>
  <div class="item__btn">
    <a href="#" class="item__link">В корзину</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="item__buy">Купить в один клик</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Забыли класс, когда ищете siblings. Должно быть

```
$(this).siblings('.item__pic-wrapper').css('border-color', '#2ecc71');
```